# Kali Linux KDE login issue

Tags: linux, kde, kali-linux

I have installed a Login theme(Caledonian) in Kde. But after rebooting there is no text field to enter username. Only a Password field, but when I enter password, it says Invalid.

I tried Console login option on the login screen, I was able to login success fully, but unable to bring up gui, also tried startx command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terminal write

```
apt-get install gnome-core kali-defaults kali-root-login desktop-base
```

Hope it will work.